# child ViewController doesn't call delegate methods declared in parent class

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a parent class: `GroupsViewController`. There is a UICollectionView Outlet inside this class connected in storyboard with UICollectionView in it's child class `NearbyGroupViewController`. All delegate methods are implemented inside parent class `GroupsViewController`. The problem is that when the `NearbyGroupViewController` is opened delegate methods are never called. what am I doing wrong?

```
class GroupsViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView
    ...
}

class NearbyGroupViewController: GroupsViewController {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your `GroupsViewController` **connected** to the `UICollectionViewDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDataSource` by either doing it programmatically (like so) or via Interface Builder.

```
self.collectionView.delegate = self
self.collectionView.datasource = self
```

EDIT:

> The problem is that when the NearbyGroupViewController is opened delegate methods are never called. what am I doing wrong?

Your `NearbyGroupViewController` needs to connect as well to the delegate and datasource of the `UICollectionView`.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with implementing the delegate methods in the parent class itself?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `delegate = self` (Instance of NearbyGroupViewController)

Means when you are making a instance of the child view controller (`NearbyGroupViewController`) in parent view controller (`GroupsViewController`) at that time you have to set this `delegate`.

```
let targetVC: NearbyGroupViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NearbyGroupViewController") as! NearbyGroupViewController
targetVC.delegate = self
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(targetVC, animated: true)
```

In above example you have to set `storyboard identifier` with `"NearbyGroupViewController"` in your storyboard file.

Answer (score -3):

try this code

```
let parent = GroupsViewController()
```

then that use

```
parent.title = ""
```